# Measure the Size(memory) of a Drawable

Tags: android, jpeg, out-of-memory

My original problem was that I was downloading a 1.3MB jpeg file and setting this as an image. This resulted in out of memory exceptions. Apparently now the server resizes the photo before I download it. However I am still getting the OOM expections. What is the easiest way to measure the size of the file that I download?

EDIT I should also mention that this runs fine on an emulator but is falling over when running on a G1

```
    public Drawable getImage() throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent();


        return Drawable.createFromStream(is, "name");


}
```

Comment: do you mean disk size or consumed memory after the image is rendered?

Comment: I want to find out what is causing the OOM exception so either I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What matters are the dimensions of the image your are downloading/loading. The memory usage will be roughly width*height*2 bytes (or *4 bytes if the image is loaded in 32 bits.) BitmapFactory provides a way to read an image's dimensions without loading the entire image. You could use this to see how big the image is going to be in memory before loading it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this via streams, every Stream child (InputStream, for example) has a read method, that returns the number of read bytes. Just count those bytes and you get the size of your image. Here's a little code example:

`while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0 , count);
            }`

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for that but I cant figure out how to incorporate it in my code. Could you help me out? I have added me code above @Egor

Comment: Initialize a byte array "data" and read the incoming bytes to it from your InputStream using this code. Then create a Drawable from this byte array. Hope I've explained it right.

Answer (score 0):

The OOM exceptions are probably happening because you are not recycling the Bitmap objects you're creating. When you render the image (I'm assuming in an ImageView) you probably want to do something like this:

```
  ImageView iv;

  // before you update the imageview with the image from the server
  if(iv.getDrawable() != null) ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
```

Comment: I only get 1 image per activity. So if I run this recycle before I get the image I wouldn't be recycling anything. Am I right in thinking that?

Comment: Well, be careful there. 1 image per activity doesn't mean you aren't creating multiple Bitmaps. Depending on your code path you may be re-inflating the image from the file and setting the ImageView's drawable. If you're doing that then you'll still need to do something like this or you WILL run out of memory. I'd recommend putting an `android.util.Log` statement in your `drawImage()` function: if it is getting called multiple times then you definitely need something like this.

Comment: I thought I was getting somewhere with Android but now I am feeling out of my depth. I don't call the drawImage() method. I create a new ImageView using the drawable that the above method returns. I am quite lost so I really appreciate your help

Comment: The crucial part of your OOM issue is that if that function is being called multiple times you will quickly run out of memory because it is creating multiple drawables. So the first step is to verify how many times that is being called, and if it is to use the `recycle()` function to free up the memory used BEFORE you create a new one.

Comment: Ok I understand that. I just have no idea how to check when the app is creating a new drawable or when to run the recycle() function. Is it something you could explain or is it possible to point me to a good resource to find out?

Comment: Perhaps http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/scarce-commodities-google-android-memory-and-bitmaps/

Comment: I can't figure out how to incorporate this in my project but thanks for taking time to help